# Kendo grid dynamic binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to dynamically bind a kendo grid control and also use custom templates for each? I can only find examples for binding a datatable page model, but the datasource must be flat. Any ideas on how to conduct dynamic binding with flat (or otherwise) display template?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean... 
"use custom templates for each" what? The templates are in a DB or something?

Maybe you can extend this example:

[Kendo UI dynamic grid creation with columns ordering grouping and paging/](http://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/asp-net-mvc-5-with-razor-kendo-ui-dynamic-grid-creation-columns-ordering-grouping-and-paging/)

...by adding another dictionary in the model that describes, with some rules, which template to use each time and using in column creation like this:

```
.Columns( columns => {
   foreach ( var c in Model.Bind )
      columns.Bound( c.Value, c.Key ).Template( Model.Templates.Where( t => t.key == c.Key).FirstOrDefault() );
 } )
```